# Flask SocketIO & uWSGI causes 'TypeError: 'SocketIO' object is not callable'

Tags: python, nginx, socket.io, uwsgi

I'm currently building an app that uses a combination of Flask and Flask SocketIO to handle a combination of HTTP and WebSocket traffic. After deploying my application on a server and adding uWSGI and Nginx as a gateway, the wsgi script gives me the following error in the logs:

```
TypeError: 'SocketIO' object is not callable
[pid: 4262|app: 0|req: 3/8] XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX () {46 vars in 912 bytes} [Tue Jul 11 14:57:25 2017] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/2.0 500) 0
```

As stated in the [uWSGI documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WebSockets.html#available-proxies), I added set `http-websockets` flag to true in my configuration file. The Flask SocketIO documentation states that they have support for uWSGI:

> The other alternative is to use the [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) web server, which comes with WebSocket functionality. The use of gevent is also a performant option, but slightly lower than eventlet.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm using the latest version of Nginx. Thanks for the help in advance. My setup:

## Flask server (mymod.server)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit


server = Flask(__name__)
io = SocketIO(server)

@server.route("/")
def index():
    return server.send_static_file("index.html")

@io.on("ping")
def ping():
    emit("pong")
```

## WSGI script (root of the project)

```
from mymod.server import io

if __name__ == "__main__":
    io.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080)
```

## WSGI config

```
# Configuration file for Nginx
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:io
master = true
processes = 5
buffer-size=32768
http-websockets = true
socket = server.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

## Nginx config

```
server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;

    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/user/project/server.sock;
    }

    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/project/server.sock;
    }
}
```

## How I start my server

```
$ uwsgi --ini config.wsgi.ini
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out Flask-SocketIO simply mounts onto the original `app` object, replacing the following:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:io
```

To:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app
```

Would work, but uwsgi still has terrible support for SocketIO, making gunicorn a better option as from what I've heard.

Comment: When i do that, uwsgi works as expected, but websocket not even working, cannot listen to /socket.io. Any hint?

Comment: @m3nda I wish I could help but i no longer work at the place where I wrote this. We also ended up just ditching Flask entirely and using FastAPI instead, which works a lot more elegantly if you ask me.

Comment: I ended up with lot of branches with "working setups", but as you said, is not elegant in any way. Thanks for your recommendation.